# VBA - Excel custom defined function gives me datatype error

Tags: excel, vba

This is my first time coding in VBA. Can anyone help me? It gives me unvalid datatype input. Where is the bug? Thank you.

```
Public Function prum(Data1 As Range) As Double()
    Dim X
    Dim result(1) As Double
    Dim count As Integer
    Dim i As Integer
    X = Data1
    count = UBound(X)

    result(0) = 0
    result(1) = 0

    For i = 1 To UBound(X)
        result(0) = X(i) + result(0)
    Next i
    result(0) = result(0) / count


    For i = 1 To UBound(X)
        result(1) = (X(i) - result(0)) * (X(i) - result(0)) + result(1)
    Next i

    result(1) = Sqr(result(1) / (count - 1) / count)


    prum = result
End Function
```

Comment: How are you calling this function? Btw an array from a range is always 2d.

Comment: *It gives me unvalid datatype input* Where? Which line?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that `X` is a 2 dimensional array.  You can convert the range values to a 1D array using `Application.Transpose`.

```
X = Application.Transpose(Data1)
```

Comment: After this edit I got error in excel with using function - "Formula contains unrecognizible text"

Comment: @AdamČervenka Strange I have never seen that error.

Comment: @AdamČervenka You could just iterate the 2D data (e.g.  `X(i, 1)`).